# Jquery + css transition only works properly when console.log(...css("left")); is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a carousel using Jquery, Javascript, and using CSS to handle the transitions of each item, but the sliding direction only works correctly when `console.log($tipToAnimate.css("left:));` is added right after the conditional statement to assign the direction. I thought at first that this might be an issue of things firing too fast, so I added a timeout before adding the `.current` class (which controls when a slide should appear) but that yielded no change in behavior. I was using classes to handle all of this and moved to using Jquery to set the CSS, but that too has yielded the same behavior.

Here's what I have:

```js
var TIPS = TIPS || {};

TIPS.animateTips = function(arrow) {
  var $arrow = $(arrow.target),
      direction = $arrow.data("direction"),
      $tip = $arrow.parent();

  animateTip($tip, direction);
};

function animateIn(self, direction) {

  if (direction == "left") {
    var $tipToAnimate = self.prev(); // find previous tip if going left
  } else if (direction == "right") {
    var $tipToAnimate = self.next(); // find next tip if going right
  }

  if ($tipToAnimate.length == 0) { // if there is no previous or next tip
    if (direction == "left") {
      $tipToAnimate = $(self).nextAll(".tip").last(); // find last tip if on first tip
    } else if (direction == "right") {
      $tipToAnimate = $(self).prevAll(".tip").last(); // find first tip if on last
    }
  }

  positionTip($tipToAnimate, direction); //this is the function that defines left
  revealTip($tipToAnimate, direction);
  $tipToAnimate.addClass("current");
}

function animateOut(self, direction) {
  self.addClass("exiting");

  if (direction == "left") {
    self.css("left", "-1400px");
  } else if (direction == "right") {
    self.css("left", "1300px");
  }

  self.removeClass("current");

  $(".exiting").one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
    $(this).css("left", "");
    $(this).addClass("hidden").removeClass("exiting");
    $(this).off("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd");
  });
}

function animateTip(self, direction) {
  animateOut(self, direction);
  animateIn(self, direction);
}

function loadCarousel() {
  $(".tip:not(.current)").addClass("hidden");
}

function positionTip(self, direction){
  if (direction == "left") {
    $(self).css("left", "1400px");
  } else if (direction == "right") {
    $(self).css("left", "-1400px");
  }
  console.log($(self).css("left")); // if this is removed, the carousel uses the css class "hidden" as the left value, even though it's being defined here
}

function revealTip(self, direction) {
  $(self).removeClass("hidden");
  $(self).css("left", "");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".arrow").bind("click", TIPS.animateTips);

  loadCarousel();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tip {
  background: #ffffff;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tip.current {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48.75em) {

  .pages-resource_prototype .tip.current {
    left: 2.5em;
  }
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tip.hidden {
  left: -1400px;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tip.exiting {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tip-content .subtitle {
  color: #5d57a2;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tip-number {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tips {
  background: #48C1C9;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tips-list {
  min-height: 35em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48.75em) {

  .pages-resource_prototype .tips-list {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "pages-resource_prototype">
<section class='tips'>
          <ul class='tips-list'>
            <li class='tip tip-0 current'>
              <div class='tip-number'>
                1
                of
                4
              </div>
              <div class='left-arrow arrow' data-direction='left'>
                <
              </div>
              <div class='right-arrow arrow' data-direction='right'>
                >
              </div>
              <div class='tip-content'>
                <h2>
                  Tip Name
                </h2>
                <p class='subtitle'>
                  Tip Type
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                  est laborum
                </p>
                <a class="appreciate" href="#appreciate"><i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
                <div class='prompt'>
                  Appreciate?
                </div>
                </a>
                <a class="download-tips" href="/">Download all tips</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class='tip tip-1 '>
              <div class='tip-number'>
                2
                of
                4
              </div>
              <div class='left-arrow arrow' data-direction='left'>
                <
              </div>
              <div class='right-arrow arrow' data-direction='right'>
                >
              </div>
              <div class='tip-content'>
                <h2>
                  Tip Name
                </h2>
                <p class='subtitle'>
                  Tip Type
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                  est laborum
                </p>
                <a class="appreciate" href="#appreciate"><i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
                <div class='prompt'>
                  Appreciate?
                </div>
                </a>
                <a class="download-tips" href="/">Download all tips</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class='tip tip-2 '>
              <div class='tip-number'>
                3
                of
                4
              </div>
              <div class='left-arrow arrow' data-direction='left'>
                <
              </div>
              <div class='right-arrow arrow' data-direction='right'>
                >
              </div>
              <div class='tip-content'>
                <h2>
                  Tip Name
                </h2>
                <p class='subtitle'>
                  Tip Type
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                  est laborum
                </p>
                <a class="appreciate" href="#appreciate"><i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
                <div class='prompt'>
                  Appreciate?
                </div>
                </a>
                <a class="download-tips" href="/">Download all tips</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class='tip tip-3 '>
              <div class='tip-number'>
                4
                of
                4
              </div>
              <div class='left-arrow arrow' data-direction='left'>
                <
              </div>
              <div class='right-arrow arrow' data-direction='right'>
                >
              </div>
              <div class='tip-content'>
                <h2>
                  Tip Name
                </h2>
                <p class='subtitle'>
                  Tip Type
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                  est laborum
                </p>
                <a class="appreciate" href="#appreciate"><i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
                <div class='prompt'>
                  Appreciate?
                </div>
                </a>
                <a class="download-tips" href="/">Download all tips</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty close. Essentially you sort of mixed up the way you were handling the animations.

If you're doing CSS animations, you should assign the animation style to the base style of the element, then adjust the properties it animates using classes. Example:

```
.element-that-animates {
    transition: left 0.4s ease-in;
}

.element-that-animates.animate {
    left: 50px;
}
```

I think what this needs is not just a `current` and `hidden` class, but rather a `current`, `left` or `right` class. The `left` and `right` classes should position a next or previous element left or right of the current element, and when the button is clicked, the current element should be given a `left` or `right` class to move it off the page, while the element that formerly had the `left` or `right` class is now given the class `current`.

It's still messy, but it'll work.

```js
var TIPS = TIPS || {};

TIPS.animateTips = function(arrow) {
  var $arrow = $(arrow.target),
      direction = $arrow.data("direction"),
      $tip = $arrow.parent();

  animateTip($tip, direction);
};

function animateIn(self, direction) {

  if (direction == "left") {
    var $tipToAnimate = self.prev(); // find previous tip if going left
  } else if (direction == "right") {
    var $tipToAnimate = self.next(); // find next tip if going right
  }

  if ($tipToAnimate.length == 0) { // if there is no previous or next tip
    if (direction == "left") {
      $tipToAnimate = $(self).nextAll(".tip").last(); // find last tip if on first tip
    } else if (direction == "right") {
      $tipToAnimate = $(self).prevAll(".tip").last(); // find first tip if on last
    }
  }

  positionTip($tipToAnimate, direction); //this is the function that defines left
  revealTip($tipToAnimate, direction);
  $tipToAnimate.addClass("current");
}

function animateOut(self, direction) {
  self.removeClass('current').addClass('hidden');
}

function animateTip(self, direction) {
  animateOut(self, direction);
  animateIn(self, direction);
}

function loadCarousel() {
  $(".tip:not(.current)").addClass("hidden");
}

function positionTip(self, direction){
  //console.log($(self).css("left")); // if this is removed, the carousel uses the css class "hidden" as the left value, even though it's being defined here
}

function revealTip(self, direction) {
  $(self).removeClass("hidden");
  $(self).css("left", "");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".arrow").bind("click", TIPS.animateTips);

  loadCarousel();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tip {
  background: #ffffff;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease;
  transition: left 0.4s ease;
}

  .pages-resource_prototype .tip.current {
    left: 2.5em;
  }

.pages-resource_prototype .tip.hidden {
  left: -1400px;
}

.page-resource_prototype .tip.current + .tip {
  left: 1400px;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tip-content .subtitle {
  color: #5d57a2;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tip-number {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tips {
  background: #48C1C9;
}

.pages-resource_prototype .tips-list {
  min-height: 35em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48.75em) {

  .pages-resource_prototype .tips-list {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "pages-resource_prototype">
<section class='tips'>
          <ul class='tips-list'>
            <li class='tip tip-0 current'>
              <div class='tip-number'>
                1
                of
                4
              </div>
              <div class='left-arrow arrow' data-direction='left'>
                <
              </div>
              <div class='right-arrow arrow' data-direction='right'>
                >
              </div>
              <div class='tip-content'>
                <h2>
                  Tip Name
                </h2>
                <p class='subtitle'>
                  Tip Type
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                  est laborum
                </p>
                <a class="appreciate" href="#appreciate"><i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
                <div class='prompt'>
                  Appreciate?
                </div>
                </a>
                <a class="download-tips" href="/">Download all tips</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class='tip tip-1 '>
              <div class='tip-number'>
                2
                of
                4
              </div>
              <div class='left-arrow arrow' data-direction='left'>
                <
              </div>
              <div class='right-arrow arrow' data-direction='right'>
                >
              </div>
              <div class='tip-content'>
                <h2>
                  Tip Name
                </h2>
                <p class='subtitle'>
                  Tip Type
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                  est laborum
                </p>
                <a class="appreciate" href="#appreciate"><i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
                <div class='prompt'>
                  Appreciate?
                </div>
                </a>
                <a class="download-tips" href="/">Download all tips</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class='tip tip-2 '>
              <div class='tip-number'>
                3
                of
                4
              </div>
              <div class='left-arrow arrow' data-direction='left'>
                <
              </div>
              <div class='right-arrow arrow' data-direction='right'>
                >
              </div>
              <div class='tip-content'>
                <h2>
                  Tip Name
                </h2>
                <p class='subtitle'>
                  Tip Type
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                  est laborum
                </p>
                <a class="appreciate" href="#appreciate"><i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
                <div class='prompt'>
                  Appreciate?
                </div>
                </a>
                <a class="download-tips" href="/">Download all tips</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class='tip tip-3 '>
              <div class='tip-number'>
                4
                of
                4
              </div>
              <div class='left-arrow arrow' data-direction='left'>
                <
              </div>
              <div class='right-arrow arrow' data-direction='right'>
                >
              </div>
              <div class='tip-content'>
                <h2>
                  Tip Name
                </h2>
                <p class='subtitle'>
                  Tip Type
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
                  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                  velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
                  est laborum
                </p>
                <a class="appreciate" href="#appreciate"><i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
                <div class='prompt'>
                  Appreciate?
                </div>
                </a>
                <a class="download-tips" href="/">Download all tips</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: I didn't assign the transition styles to the base element because when going from a "hidden" to a "ready for animation" state, the element risks flying across the screen depending on the direction of animation. I agree with you regarding the use of classes vs. Jquery to handle positioning: it was my first approach but I went with this in an effort to troubleshoot. Using classes instead still doesn't solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `setTimeout` function can solve the problem. If I add a 100ms timeout to calling the `revealTip` function (after the `positionTip` function is called), the carousel behaves as expected. I believe this is because `console.log` was delaying the execution of the animation and thus enabling it to run.

If anyone has feedback as to how I can avoid using `setTimeout` here I'd like to hear it. Using `setTimeout` feels a tad messy.